# How to compair pairs in to arrays and select only those that satisfy a condition?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

There are two lists:

```
L1 = {{12, 12}, {7, 15}, {15, 0}, {0, 17}, {17, 8}, {8, 2}, {2, 
    0}, {0, 9}, {9, 0}, {0, 3}, {3, 0}, {0, 16}, {16, 18}, {18, 
    1}, {1, 16}, {16, 18}, {18, 4}, {4, 9}, {9, 3}, {3, 1}, {1, 
    1}, {1, 18}, {18, 14}, {14, 11}, {11, 10}, {10, 1}, {1, 9}, {9, 
    2}, {2, 0}, {0, 17}, {17, 19}, {19, 2}, {2, 20}, {20, 1}, {1, 
    6}, {6, 2}, {2, 15}, {15, 8}, {8, 4}, {4, 9}};

L2 = {14 -> 2, 2 -> 14, 9 -> 10, 20 -> 8, 5 -> 1, 9 -> 5, 19 -> 11, 
   2 -> 12, 18 -> 5, 0 -> 11, 15 -> 18, 19 -> 6, 14 -> 4, 9 -> 14, 
   0 -> 19, 1 -> 13, 13 -> 17, 15 -> 5, 13 -> 0, 12 -> 12};
```

The goal is to find if one of the pairs from L1 is in L2 and select it from L2. For example: I can see that {12,12} from L1 exists in L2 in the form of 12->12, so I need to select it.
I can do it by hand like:

```
Select[L2, #1[[1]] == 12 && #1[[2]] == 12 &]
{12 -> 12}
```

But the goal is to go through all pairs in L1 and get a new list of all coincidences. So I need to expand my approach for a whole list, but don't know how to reach this goal.

Comment: Try with `Select[L2, MemberQ[L1, List @@ #] &]`

Comment: Or `Rule @@@ Intersection[L1, List @@@ L2]`.

Comment: `Intersection[Rule @@@ L1, L2]` is basically the same as @Rohit's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
Rule @@@ Union @@ Nearest[List @@@ L2, L1, {\[Infinity], 0}]
```